# Apache giving 301 redirect for POST from a payment gateway response

Tags: apache2, payment-gateway, mod-proxy

I have a tomcat application running behind apache which handles response from the payment gateway. The configuration looks like below

ProxyPass /web http//localhost:8090/web/
ProxyPassReverse /web http://localhost:8090/web/

After I redirect to payment gateway, the payment gateway sends a POST request to my server at 
https://example.com/web/payments/payu/success
 And this causes apache to give a response back saying 301, Permanently moved.
But I have a servlet capable of handling this request. And this causes another GET call to the same URL but without any params from the last post.

Does anyone have an idea why is this behaviour? I searched all over internet for a solution, but I could not find anything which could give me some clue. This looks like a common scenario in integrating the payment gateways. Does this has anything to do with CORS. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use a few tools to detect the issue.  First is something like Postman to simulate the data being sent to your server... second is on the server side, enable if possible verbose logging and tail the logs to see what is going on with the post.  It could be something simple, I've seen some frameworks require a trailing slash.  Or something along those lines.